# ListPlot doesn't shows all points

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics, version-7

I have a table:
`p1 = Table[(Binomial[2000, k]*StirlingS2[1386, k]*k!)/(2000^1386), {k, 1, 1386, 
    1}];`

I used `ListPlot[p1]` to draw a plot of this values. This is the plot, where on `Y` I have values of `p1` and on `X` I have values of `k`. But when I draw my plot, I see only points which are starting from $k \approx 560$. Why I can't see points for all values of `k`?
Is this because of that values for small `k` are too small?
How can I fix that?

Comment: Just add `PlotRange->Full`.

Comment: @Pickett It doesn't helped.

Comment: @picket and closers: `PlotRange` isn't the issue here. The points Zia is missing (before about k =560) fall within the visible range but are simply not plotted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to evaluate numerically the points, using N[]. Morevoer, I always suggest you to use the PlotRange->All option for ListPlot. Here is the code:

```
p1 = Table[(Binomial[2000, k]*StirlingS2[1386, k]*k!)/(2000^1386), {k,1, 1386, 1}] 

ListPlot[p1 // N, PlotRange -> All]
```

This shows all the values starting from k=1.

Comment: Now everything works good. Thank you, from now on I will remember using N[].

Comment: @ziva Usually, `ListPlot` works just fine without `N`, but the numbers in your table are a bit extreme (just have a look at `p[[1]]` and `p[[800]]`) and I think `ListPlot` removes the smallest/most hopeless cases. `Cases[ListPlot[p1, PlotRange -> All], Point[p___] :> Length@p, Infinity]` shows that there are 849 points in the arbitrary precision plot. If you use `p1//N` in the above you'll see you have 1386 points instead.